# How to do sorting by Day and Hour field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a string value as `07052018080504623`

It represents `MM DD YYYY HH MM SS MS`

means

```
MM = 07, DD = 05, YYYY=2018, HH = 08, MM=05 , SS= 04, MS = 623
```

Now I have a table defined as

```
declare @t table (WorkRequestId varchar(100))
insert into @t values
('07052018080504623'),('07062018012756663'),('07062018020148130'),('07062018095201231'),
('07062018102203805'),('07062018103718059'),('07062018110304836'),('07062018115356135'),
('07062018120624983'),('07062018124035480'),('07062018080504623'),('07062018070504623')

select 
    *   
from @t
```

The records should be sorted in ascending order such that

```
WorkRequestId

07052018080504623
07062018095201231
07062018102203805
07062018103718059
07062018110304836
07062018115356135
07062018120624983
07062018124035480
07062018012756663
07062018020148130
```

The cutoff time is 8PM of previous day to 19:59:59 PM of next day.
In our example, 05 is previous day while 06 is next day.

Also no transaction happens between 1AM - 7:59:59 AM of next day. It starts again from 8AM of next day and continues till
19:59:59 PM.

So when we encounter `07062018012756663, the DD=06 and HH = 01`. It means `13HRs (i.e. 1PM) of 6th`. Same for `07062018020148130 where DD=06 and HH = 02 (i.e. 2PM or 14Hrs).`

But `07062018095201231 where DD=06 and HH = 09 means 9AM of 6th.`

That is why

```
07062018095201231 comes before 07062018012756663 and 07062018020148130
```

while ordering

My attempt so far (not correct yet)

```
select 
    *       
    ,DY=SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],3,2)
    ,HH = SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],9,2)
    ,CurrentDY=CONVERT(varchar(2), getdate(), 103)
from @t

order by left([WorkRequestId],8) + 
    cast(iif( 
            SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],3,2) = '6',--CONVERT(varchar(2), getdate(), 103), 
            iif(cast(SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],9,2) as int) between 1 and 7,
            cast(SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],9,2) as int)+12,SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],9,2)),
            cast(SUBSTRING([WorkRequestId],9,2)as varchar(4)))as varchar(20))
    +right([WorkRequestId],7)
```

Comment: If you're dealing with days and hours - you should use the **most appropriate** datatypes - e.g. `DATE` and `TIME` (or `DATETIME2(n)`) and **not** store dates and times as strings !!

Comment: "I have a string value..." There's your problem right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
select 
    *
from @t 
order by left (WorkRequestId, 8) + (case when SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 9,2) between '01' and '07' then CAST(SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 9,2) + 12 AS CHAR(2)) else SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 9,2) end) +  SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 11,7)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I guess you should realize by now that storing dates as strings (and in fact, storing anything in the wrong data type) is bad practice.
The correct solution is to change the database structure to hold that data as `DateTime2` instead of a string. However, assuming this can't be done for some reason, you can get the results you want by converting the string values to `datetime2`, adding 12 hours where the hour is between 1 a.m. and 8 a.m., and sort by that date.
I've written my suggestion in a cumbersome way because I wanted to show every part of the process - I've used 3 common table expression though if can be done in a single query - again, that's just to illustrate every step of the solution:

```
;WITH CTEDateParts AS -- break down the string to it's parts
(
    SELECT  WorkRequestId, 
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 5, 4) As Year,
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 1, 2) As Month,
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 3, 2) As Day,
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 9, 2) As Hour,
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 11, 2) As Minute,
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 13, 2) As Second,
            SUBSTRING(WorkRequestId, 15, 3) As Millisecond
    FROM @t
), CTEDates AS -- create datetime values from the string parts
(
    SELECT  WorkRequestId, 
            CAST(Year +'-'+ Month +'-'+ Day +'T'+ 
                 Hour +':'+ Minute +':'+ Second +'.'+ Millisecond As DateTime2(7)) As DateValue
    FROM CTEDateParts
), CTEFixedDates AS -- add 12 hours for hours between 1 and 8 a.m.
(
    SELECT  WorkRequestId, 
            DateValue,
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, DateValue) >= 1 AND DATEPART(HOUR, DateValue) <= 8 THEN 
                DATEADD(Hour, 12, DateValue)
            ELSE
                DateValue
            END As FixedDate 
    FROM CTEDates
)

-- finally, select order by the FixedDate column
SELECT WorkRequestId
FROM CTEFixedDates
ORDER BY FixedDate
```

Results:

```
WorkRequestId
07052018080504623
07062018095201231
07062018102203805
07062018103718059
07062018110304836
07062018115356135
07062018120624983
07062018124035480
07062018012756663
07062018020148130
07062018070504623
07062018080504623
```